# Get JDBC API level via JDBC API?

Tags: jdbc

Is it possible to get JDBC level API support via JDBC API?

That is `3.0`, `3.1`, `4.0`, `4.1`, `4.2`, etc...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can using

- [`DatabaseMetaData.getJDBCMajorVersion()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getJDBCMajorVersion--)

  > Retrieves the major JDBC version number for this driver.
- and [`DatabaseMetaData.getJDBCMinorVersion()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getJDBCMinorVersion--):

  > Retrieves the minor JDBC version number for this driver.

This was added in Java 1.4 (JDBC 3); note that there is no JDBC 3.1.

So

```
Connection connection = ....
DatabaseMetaData dbmd = connection.getDatabaseMetaData();
System.out.printf("JDBC: %d.%d%n", dbmd.getJDBCMajorVersion(), dbmd.getJDBCMinorVersion());
```

Answer (score 0):

For:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
  <version>12.1.3-0-0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
  <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
  <version>10.13.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.195</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
  <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

and:

```
    Class.forName(org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver.class.getCanonicalName());
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mydb", "sa", "");
    System.out.println(String.format("HSQLDB: %s.%s", meta.getJDBCMajorVersion(), meta.getJDBCMinorVersion()));

    Class.forName(org.h2.Driver.class.getCanonicalName());
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:mydb", "sa", "");
    System.out.println(String.format("H2: %s.%s", meta.getJDBCMajorVersion(), meta.getJDBCMinorVersion()));

    Class.forName(org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.class.getCanonicalName());
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:memory:mydb;create=true");
    System.out.println(String.format("Derby: %s.%s", meta.getJDBCMajorVersion(), meta.getJDBCMinorVersion()));

    Class.forName(oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.class.getCanonicalName());
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE", "sa", "");
    System.out.println(String.format("Oracle: %s.%s", meta.getJDBCMajorVersion(), meta.getJDBCMinorVersion()));
```

I've got:

```
HSQLDB: 3.0
H2: 4.0
Derby: 4.2
Oracle: 4.1
```

Interesting inconsistency with `com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.3`:

```
Oracle: 1.12
```